# What is the easiest way to tag user-submitted questions with category tags on a Django-base site?

Tags: django, categories

I am building a site in Django where users submit questions about a wide range of topics. When a question is submitted, I would like it to be tagged with the various categories to which it belongs so it can be grouped with related questions. For example, if someone asks "does breastfeeding increase the risk of cancer?", I want that question tagged with categories like "child care, breastfeeding, cancer, etc". I understand that categorizing content is a common issue and I am curious what the best options are.

Comment: Please read the [help] before posting. Sadly this question is considered WAY too broad for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're trying to achieve is not just a programming issue, because it has something to do with what I call **AI**, or **artificial intelligence**, which makes computers think somehow like humans.

Suppose you have these categories : sport, health, child care, politics, ....

If I post this question : **"How bad can sport affect our health ?"**

You can just split the question into words, as the words **sport** and **health** are  categories, so that question can easily be tagged with them.

Now if I post this question : **" Did Cristiano Ronaldo refuse to donate $25000 to children ? "**

This question doesn't have any words that are categories. However, by using our human mind, we can see that this questions belongs to those categories : sport, child care, society...

So the first algorithm is not suitable, and you will have to look for more ways and techniques that belong to artificial intelligence, things like machine learning, neural networks, semantics...

If you want to avoid all of this, you can just let the user select the categories that match his question, like what we do here in Stack Overflow, when we chose tags for our questions.

I hope that my answer will be helpful

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do that is simply provide users some tags to manual choose using ManyToMany relationship. For example:

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=40)


class Question(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    text = models.TextField()
    tags = models.ManyToMany(Tag)
```

Then you can create new tags and mark your questions,for example:

```
>>> tag1 = Tag(title='science')
>>> tag1.save()
>>> tag2 = Tag(title='music')
>>> tag2.save()
>>> tag3 = Tag(title='computers')
>>> tag3.save()
>>> question = Question(title='Question about science', text='very important question')
>>> question.save()
>>> question.tags.add(tag1)
```

Please, notice that you can add tags to only already saved objects. You can read more about Many-To-Many relationship in [official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/)